# question about "neo4j query" (combine two result)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j and cypher.
and have a question about cypher.
there are my results.

result 1)

```
MATCH (f:Fruit)-[r0]-(a:Animal)-[r1]-(h:Human)-[r2]-(p:Plant) where p.type = 'Flower' RETURN *;
```

result 2)

```
MATCH (p:Plant)-[r3]-(t:Threat) where p.type = 'Flower' RETURN *;
```

-->
There are relationship and graph are drawn.

but, I want combine two result.
Is there any way?
Thank you, ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to combine results.

```
UNION ALL

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/
```

then to remove any duplicates; use  UNION  (without ALL)

In your example:

```
 MATCH (f:Fruit)-[r0]-(a:Animal)-[r1]-(h:Human)-[r2]-(p:Plant) 
 where p.type = 'Flower'
 RETURN p, null as t
 UNION ALL
 MATCH (p:Plant)-[r3]-(t:Threat) 
 where p.type = 'Flower' 
 RETURN p, t

 Sample Result:
╒══════════╤════════════════╕
│"p"       │"t"             │
╞══════════╪════════════════╡
│{"name":3}│null            │
├──────────┼────────────────┤
│{"name":3}│{"id":"some_id"}│
└──────────┴────────────────┘
```

All columns that you return must have the same name so I made a hack on naming "null" as t.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

1.
Can I get all the node and relationship information in 'union all' query?
(include fruit, r0, animal, r1, human, r2, plant, threat, r3)

2. 
Can I use union all by adding one more match query? (3 match querys)